# What does the phrase: "the age of ...." mean?

Tags: expressions, idioms

So for instance if someone says:  *This is the age of Bob.*

For me (non-native) this always felt like:  This is the year where everything will work out for Bob.

However I might be completely wrong here. Unfortunately this expression seems ungoogleable for me.

Comment: I don't think it's so much that everything will work out for Bob, as that Bob is suddenly a pivotal figure (by analogy with, say, the Age of Sail).

Comment: I've always heard it as **This is Bob's year**

Comment: The Age of Alexander the Great would make enough sense, meaning the period in time when he ruled.  But the phrase "the age of" is not exactly in common use in the case where the person (Bob) is not a person of historical significance, even as a joke.  Your interpretation of it, assuming some amount of humor is intended, reminds me of "Summer of George" from Seinfeld - the summer when George expects to have a great time and, like you say, for everything to work out for him.  But I haven't heard "age of" used this way.

Comment: Thanks... This all makes a lot of sense.